# Double Literally Result False

Tags: java, integer, double, wrapper

My Question about Wrapper classes. Case 1: I'm Declaring two `Integer` variables and assigning same values **`127`**,  and i'm printing both hashCode. It's Generated same hashCode and result will be printed `true`. But In Case 2: Generated the Same hashCode but result will be printing `false`. Please Could you relate. Why Printing a `false` result.

```
package com.oca.test.exam;

public class TestCasesIntegerAndDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Case 1:
        Integer i1 = 127;
        Integer i2 = 127;

        System.out.println(i1.hashCode()); //127
        System.out.println(i2.hashCode()); //127
        System.out.println(i1 == i2); //true

        //Case 2:
        Double d1 = 127.0;
        Double d2 = 127.0;

        System.out.println(d1.hashCode());//1080016896
        System.out.println(d2.hashCode());//1080016896
        System.out.println(d1 == d2); //false
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shmosel Your question is different. Please Read First My Question Then Mark Duplicate.

Comment: The question is a little different, but the answer is the same.

Comment: i know that integer cases but i'm talking about Case 2:.

Comment: See the second link.

Comment: i already check the second link but second link is talking only Integer type. Not Double Type case.

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: I know that Integer Case. Integer pool lie between -128 to 127;

Comment: Is Not Same Thing I See The Integer Api valueOf() Method : http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html

Comment: Double Api http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Double.java.html

Comment: if you say that, is a  same thing. then Why Case2 is False. Because I'm entering the number between -128 to 127 .When result is printing false.

Comment: There's no cache for Double, only Integer.

Comment: public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Integer x = 1000;
        long y = 1000;
        Integer z = 1000;
        System.out.println(x==y); //true doubt in this place
        System.out.println(x==z); //false this statement not lie -128to127. it okay
    }

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: yes this a question

Comment: And the question is?